# How to Map a JPA One-to-Many Relationship For Cascade Deletion

Tags: java, database, jpa, entity, rdbms

I'm getting really confused with how to map a JPA One to Many Relationship so that I can cascade delete.

I have Yard

```
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "yard", schema = "example")
    public class Yard {
        @Id
        @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
        @Column(name="yard_num")
        long yardNum;

        @Column(name="sqft")
        Integer sqft;
    }
```

And Flower

```
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "flower", schema = "example")
    public class Flower {
        @Id
        @Column(flower_id)
        long flowerId

        @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="yard_num")            
        long yardNum;
     
        @Column(name="num_petals")
        Integer numPetals;
    }
```

A yard can have many flowers or exist without Flowers but each Flower needs exactly one yard. If a yard gets deleted the flowers should be cascade deleted too. There is a foreign key on Flower for yard_num.

I thought that was OneToMany unidirectional from Yard to Flower. But I'm getting an error putting a OneToMany tag on Yard's yardNum and a @ManyToOne tag on Flower's yardNum. Why do these need to be collections? Also do I have my other tags correct (JoinColumn)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **Yard** can have many **Flowers** as you mentioned, so the concept is that the entity **Yard** has to include a collection of entities **Flower**s (not longs, etc.), maybe empty btw. And the entity **Flower** must have an entity **Yard** (not Yard's id)

I'll provide an entities mapping, not tested, but idea is that I mentioned above:

**Yard:**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "yard", schema = "example")
public class Yard {

  @Id
  @Column(name="yard_num")
  Long yardNum;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "yard", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
  List<Flower> flowers = new ArrayList<>();

  @Column(name = "sqft")
  Integer sqft;
}
```

**Flower:**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "flower", schema = "example")
public class Flower {
    @Id
    @Column(name="flower_id")
    Long flowerId

    @ManyToOne
    // you have to define FK to table "yard" here, if its name is "yard_num" so it's OK
    @JoinColumn(name="yard_num")           
    Yard yard;
    
    @Column(name="num_petals")
    Integer numPetals;
}
```